# Creating a javascript module that imports and patch another

Tags: javascript, module, umd

I am trying to write a JavaScript module that will be imported in the browser. This module should import and patch another which uses UMD (Universal Module Definition).

In this new module I do `import 'old.js';` I get the following `TypeError: root is undefined`. What is the correct way to do it?